# How to deploy ClusterRoleBinding in Google Kubernetes Engine for KubeIP

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, rbac

I am seeing an RBAC failure when trying to deploy [KubeIP](https://kubeip.com/) to GKE.

I have isolated the issue down to the following section of the [KubeIP infrastructure](https://github.com/doitintl/kubeip/blob/master/deploy/kubeip-deployment.yaml#L68):

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: kubeip-sa
  namespace: kube-system
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["nodes"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch","patch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get","list","watch"]
```

I am getting the following error from `kubectl` and GKE:

> Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "template.yml": clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "kubeip-sa" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges: [{[get] [] [nodes] [] []} {[list] [] [nodes] [] []} {[watch] [] [nodes] [] []} {[patch] [] [nodes] [] []} {[get] [] [pods] [] []} {[list] [] [pods] [] []} {[watch] [] [pods] [] []}] user=&{108986779198363313539  [system:authenticated] map[user-assertion.cloud.google.com:[AKUJVpldMDXqrDZ2slnJReDbLytxt6P2EEyEBbLNRB90oOATH4vIURo/lIhaBuAj9nnwwyxJDSxj2OdCyjjgBC/s5QxftIJnr8128ToTglCzk+e8Wybt4heIizRHugWnIhKNqkF+B0yiv0pIxgOfakma+SbkzbQbVzJPtgxsmHmak30YfPA58n/xyJ8R7oNVJ5dFUAWDFNsqHf/auolViw0Zd7Cr4aYYDXX4GScw==]]} ownerrules=[{[create] [authorization.k8s.io] [selfsubjectaccessreviews selfsubjectrulesreviews] [] []} {[get] [] [] [] [/api /api/* /apis /apis/* /healthz /openapi /openapi/* /swagger-2.0.0.pb-v1 /swagger.json /swaggerapi /swaggerapi/* /version /version/]}] ruleResolutionErrors=[]

I have crated the appropriate ~/.kube/config by issuing

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster> \
  --zone <zone> \
  --project <project>
```

The gcloud service account I am using has been granted cluster-admin in the GKE cluster in question

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
  --clusterrole cluster-admin \
  --user $(gcloud config get-value account)
```

I can verify that my service account user should have the cluster-admin role checking my current gcloud user and checking the GKE ClusterRoleBinding

```
$ gcloud config get-value account
terraform@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com

$ kubectl describe clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding
Name:         cluster-admin-binding
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  cluster-admin
Subjects:
  Kind  Name                                                Namespace
  ----  ----                                                ---------
  User  terraform@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

According to kubectl I *should* be able to create ClusterRoleBindings

```
$ kubectl auth can-i create clusterrolebinding
yes
```

Does anybody see what element of GKE RBAC I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer at this question "[Creating a ClusterRole as the default compute service account fails with extra privileges error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770198/creating-a-clusterrole-as-the-default-compute-service-account-fails-with-extra-p)" guided me to the solution.

If you map the ClusterRoleBinding to the service account id instead of the email everything works as expected.

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding \
  --clusterrole cluster-admin \
  --user $(gcloud iam service-accounts describe <service account email> --format="value(uniqueId)")
```